# Replacing one empty table with another table without affecting Foreign Keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

- I have migrated a database using **structure only**
- In this database I have a table called `hash` that is empty, of course.
- This table is being used by tons of other tables through `foreign key`.
- I have another table called `hash_copy` that has been just copied from another database and is full of records (500'000 records).

I tried to replace one table by another with the following SQL Statement

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
RENAME TABLE hash to hash_empty, hash_copy to hash;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Problem is that now all my foreing keys are poiting to `hash_empty` which is what I was trying to avoid.

### To sumup

I'd like to turn off Foreign Keys just to swap one table for another (throw the empty away and plug the full of records) without having to go through all the tables that makes references to it.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't `INSERT INTO hash SELECT * FROM hash_copy`? Sure, it won't be as fast, but 500k records shouldn't take that long to copy.

Comment: @jbafford pretty amazing that stuff. It took 10 seconds to migrate the whole table. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, a table can be copied to another table like:

```
INSERT INTO hash SELECT * from hash_copy
```

More generally, the insert-select syntax works like as you would expect; you can specify column names (`INSERT INTO hash(col1, col2, col3)`) and include any `SELECT` syntax you normally would (functions, joins, where clauses, etc).